# Zsh completion for global aliases

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion, zsh-alias

Is there a way to get tab completion for global aliases in zsh? Defined as:

```
% alias -g zshplugins=~/.zshplugins
```

`% nvim zshpl[tab]` would not tab complete.

I use global aliases mainly to not have to enter the path to a file nor restrict myself to a single command (e.g., `alias zshplugin="nvim ~/.zshplugins"`)

I understand that these are also meant to be used inside arbitrary one-liners (a global alias for `| grep -i`, for instance) and don't make sense to suggest on every tab stroke, but If there's some workaround to include these in directory/file completion, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the shell variable but not global alias.

But if you want, add following code to your `zshrc`

```
_complete_alias() {
    [[ -n $PREFIX ]] && compadd -- ${(M)${(k)galiases}:#$PREFIX*}
    return 1
}
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete_alias _complete _ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

Would `zshpl[tab]` complete at the beginning of the line (leaving out nvim)? This what I should work. An alias is not meant to be used as a shortcut for a file name. Shell variables can be used for the latter (and there is a completion on them too). I suggest that you define

```
zshplugins=~/.zshplugins
```

and then do

```
nvim $zshpl[tab]
```